# lazypredict.Supervised.LazyClassifier. ImportError: Cannot import name '_raise_dep_warning_if_not_pytest' from 'sklearn.utils.deprecation'

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

I tried:

```
from lazypredict.Supervised import LazyClassifier
```

But got the following traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-f518cae57501> in <module>
     10 from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
     11 from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
---> 12 from lazypredict.Supervised import LazyClassifier
     13 from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
     14 from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\lazypredict\Supervised.py in <module>
     14 from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, OneHotEncoder, OrdinalEncoder
     15 from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
---> 16 from sklearn.utils.testing import all_estimators
     17 from sklearn.base import RegressorMixin
     18 from sklearn.base import ClassifierMixin

S:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\testing.py in <module>
      5 from . import _testing  # type: ignore
      6 from ..externals._pep562 import Pep562
----> 7 from ..utils.deprecation import _raise_dep_warning_if_not_pytest
      8 
      9 deprecated_path = 'sklearn.utils.testing'

ImportError: cannot import name '_raise_dep_warning_if_not_pytest' from 'sklearn.utils.deprecation' (S:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\deprecation.py)
```

I was working in a Jupyter notebook, and have already tried upgrading `scikit-learn` too.

Comment: `LazyClassifier` is a 3rd party package (https://github.com/shankarpandala/lazypredict), it is not imported from scikit-learn.

Comment: What versions are you running? (e.g. What is the output of: `pip freeze | grep "scikit-learn` and `pip freeze | grep lazypredict`)

Answer (score 5):

This is most likely caused by incompatible versions of `lazypredict` and `scikit-learn`. Per the current LazyPredict requirements file, it needs [`scikit-learn==0.23.1`](https://github.com/shankarpandala/lazypredict/blob/3d62db32c0058039fcde9a2322d7e88d13473bb3/requirements.txt#L8).

This should be fixed with:

```
pip uninstall scikit-learn -y
pip install scikit-learn==0.23.1
```

Comment: I actually had to install lazypredict again. It works now. As you said, it was probably because both their versions were incompatible. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

In case it helps someone else, the above solution to install scikit-learn version 0.23.1 didn't work for me.  I'm using Anaconda and did `conda update --all` and then ran `conda install scikit-learn-intelex` and the import worked for me afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

my error was resolved by doing this:

```
!pip uninstall scikit-learn -y
!pip install scikit-learn==0.24
```